# htaccess redirect root to rewritten subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a tricky htaccess problem I can't seem to figure out

A webapp was written in /2/

We previously rewrote /card/ to /2/ for prettier urls

Now we are rewriting /ss-card/ to /2/ for a more clearly defined url

however /2/ is still accessible and we would like /2/ to redirect to /ss-card/ and the attempts I have made have ended in redirect loops

My question is, is this even possible?

Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ss-card
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2

Redirect 301 /card /ss-card
Redirect 301 /card/ /ss-card/

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ss-card/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ss-card/card$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/card/$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/card/(.*)$ /ss-card/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^card$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ss-card$ /2/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/?$ /2/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/(.*)$ /2/$1 [L,NC]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try checking for `/2/` in the `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+2/
RewriteRule ^2/(.*)$ /ss-card/$1 [L,R=301]

Redirect 301 /card /ss-card
Redirect 301 /card/ /ss-card/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ss-card
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/2
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ss-card/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ss-card/card$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/card/$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/card/(.*)$ /ss-card/$1 [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^card$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]
RewriteRule ^card/?$ /ss-card/ [R=302,L,NC]

RewriteRule ^ss-card$ /2/ [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ss-card/?$ /2/ [L,NC]
```

RewriteRule ^ss-card/(.*)$ /2/$1 [L,NC]